# How to get selected percentage discount all products

Tags: products, discount

I want to get specific percentage (i.e 5%) discount all products. how can I get the products?

I am using Magento 1.7.0.2 and trying with below code for all selected products:

```
    $_pro_collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
    $_pro_collection->getSelect()->order('(price_index.final_price / price_index.price)', 'DESC');
```

Your help will be appreciated. Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below code:

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('special_price', array('gt' => 0));
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('price', array('gt' => 0));
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('special_price', array('eq' => new Zend_Db_Expr('`at_price`.`value`*0.95')));

/** for FLAT CATALOG use this line
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('special_price', array('eq' => new Zend_Db_Expr('e.price*0.95')));
**/

/**
ADD EXTRA FILTER HERE
**/
```

Adding From and To Date Filters

```
$date = strtotime(date('Y-m-d')); 
$current_date = date("Y-m-d hh:mm:ss",$date);
$collection= $specialcollection->addAttributeToFilter(array(
    array('attribute'=>'special_from_date','lteq'=>$current_date),
    array('attribute'=>'special_from_date','eq'=>''),
    array('attribute'=>'special_from_date','null'=>true)
),'','left')
->addAttributeToFilter(array(
    array('attribute'=>'special_to_date','gteq'=>$current_date),
    array('attribute'=>'special_to_date','eq'=>''),
    array('attribute'=>'special_to_date','null'=>true)
),'','left');
```

Comment: I am using version 1.7.0.2. Above code is not working in my setup. In which version you checked?

Comment: Checked in 1702 also and it's working, What's an error you are getting ?

Comment: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'at_price.value' in 'where clause'

Comment: do `echo $collection->getSelect()` after this line `$collection->addAttributeToFilter('special_price', array('eq' => new Zend_Db_Expr('`at_price`.`value`*0.95')));` and show here

Comment: SELECT 1 AS `status`, `e`.`entity_id`, `e`.`type_id`, `e`.`attribute_set_id`, `e`.`special_price`, `e`.`price` FROM `catalog_product_flat_1` AS `e` WHERE (e.special_price > 0) AND (e.price > 0) AND (e.special_price = `at_price`.`value`*0.95)

Comment: So you are using FLAT catalog, use this `$collection->addAttributeToFilter('special_price', array('eq' => new Zend_Db_Expr('e.price*0.95')));`
OR
`$collection->addAttributeToFilter('special_price', array('eq' => new Zend_Db_Expr('price*0.95')));`

Comment: it's working after replace ->addAttributeToFilter('special_price', array('eq' => new Zend_Db_Expr('`e`.`price`*0.95'))); instade of addAttributeToFilter('special_price', array('eq' => new Zend_Db_Expr('`at_price`.`value`*0.95')));

Comment: Glad that helps, updated the answer